# Bus Error: 10 returned when trying to pass chars between methods

Tags: c, pointers, char

Hi im new to the c language and haven't fully got my head around pointers. I am writing a simple username/password authentication process for my program it currently looks like this:

```
void authenticate_process(int cli_sockfd){

    /* Authentication Process */
    write(cli_sockfd, "USN", 3);
    char *username;
    username = recv_msg(cli_sockfd);
    printf("[DEBUG] Client username is %s.\n", username);

    write(cli_sockfd, "PSW", 3);
    char *password;
    password = recv_msg(cli_sockfd);
    printf("[DEBUG] Client Password is %s.\n", password);

//From Here the program breaks 
    bool approval = authenticate_login(username, password);
    printf("%c", approval);
}


bool authenticate_login(char *username, char *password)
{
    printf("Made it here");

    FILE *file;
    char *file_username;
    char *file_password;
    bool match;
    printf("%s", username);
    printf("%s", password);
// BLAH BLAH BLAH MORE CODE IN THIS SECTION 

    return match;
}
```

I can obtain and print out the clients username and password in the authenticate_process method but once i get to the line `bool approval = authenticate_login(username, password);` i get `Bus Error: 10` I believe it has to do with how i pass chars but i could be wrong. Can someone please explain and show me how to fix my problem?

Comment: Make sure diagnostic messages end with a newline.   On many systems, the output won't appear until there's a newline, or until a fairly large buffer is full (with anywhere from 512 to 4096 characters).  Your 'made it here' message may not appear immediately.  Either add the newline at the end, or use `fflush(stdout)`, or both.  Similar with printing the user name and password; you won't be able to reliably separate those from each other with the printing as shown.

Comment: You don't show the `recv_msg` function, but one possible problem is that it does not allocate space properly.  You save whatever it returns, but there could be all sorts of problems if it returns a pointer to a local variable, for example.